# Create join with polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have two tables with the polymorphic relationships.

Invoice Table:

```
public function transactions(){
    return $this->morphMany(TransactionAllocation::class, 'doc');
}
```

Payment Table:

```
public function doc()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

This relationship works fine if I use `with`.
But when I am trying to use join, this does not work. [Related Laravel Doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses)

```
DB::table('invoices')
->join('transactions', function ($join){
   $join->on('invoices.id','=','transactions.doc_id')
   ->where('transactions.doc_type','App\Models\Invoice');
})
->get()
```

Here is the error I get:

```
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'transactions.doc_id' 
in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `invoices` inner join `transactions` 
on `invoices`.`id` = `transactions`.`doc_id` 
and `transactions`.`doc_type` = App\Models\Invoice)
```

Comment: Please check your `doc_id` first in your `transactions` table

Comment: @A.ANoman check what? There is a doc_id. That is how the polymorphic relation works when I eager load it using `with`